# Position of a particle moving along a straight line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A particle moves along a straight line, for $0 \leq t \leq 7, t$ is measured in minutes. The velocity of the particle, in meters/minute, is given by $v(t) = t^3 - 11t^2 + 34t - 24.$

a) What is the velocity of the particle at time $t=2?$

b) When is the particle at rest?

c) When is the particle moving forward and when is it moving backward?

d) When is the particle speeding up and slowing down?

a) I understand that you can just plug in $2$ for the derivative of the given function. I got $2\frac{m}{s}$

b)This is the part that I am stuck on. I tried to factor the terms for $v'(t) = 3t^2-22t+34$ but it just wouldn't work for me so I tried to solve it with a quadratic and got $(22-\sqrt{76})/6.$

c/d) I kind of understand how to do this. When moving backwards and forwards I can plug in certain # of the line and compare the velociy to the acceleration(-- speeding up ++ speeding up +- slow down) but it would be greatly appreciated if I can get a better method/better explanation that might make more sense.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Wording

Comment: Note that the function $v(t)$ given is already the velocity, so you don't need to take the derivative to do parts a through c.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to math.stackexchange.com ! Please format your question using MathJax. See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Your velocity function simplifies to $(t-1)(t-4)(t-6)$ so there are $3$ roots and that should also lead you to the next part as to when the velocity is negative vs. positive.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to MSE! In general for such cases that require factorization on the spot, you can always try plugging in $t=1$ as an easy first case, $1-11+34-24=0$ so $t-1$ is a factor of your velocity function, from which you can find the remaining factors because now you would have $(t-1)\cdot$ a quadratic. @MathLover has simplified the quadratic!

Comment: What Math Lover said. You are given an equation for *velocity*, not displacement... so no need to differentiate for part (b).